# Item.Restrict Function doesn't work when using like instead of =

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I'm creating a macro that pulls e-mail attachments into a folder to be opened and copied, which works 100% perfect when the subject name is predefined, i.e. never changes.

```vb
' this works
Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = " & SubjectName)
```

However, when I try to instead restrict for a preset beginning, say every email begins with 'aaaaa', it causes an automation error with the code below:

```vb
' this doesnt
Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] like '" & PrefixName & "%'")
```

Any help?

Expected results: No error message, files in folder. Instead I receive

> Run-time error '-2147352567 (800200009)': Automation error Exception Occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an email starting with specific subject using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30464271/11683)

Comment: You are missing "@SQL=" prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code instead:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '" & PrefixName & "%'" 
Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict(criteria)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not really familiar with SQL. Sorry to be a pain but If I also wanted to filter by the systems current date so that it only takes today's emails, how would I go about doing that / learning to do that

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering