# Referencing a shared inbox, ERROR: assignment to constant not permitted

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code that will:

1. Go to a specific folder ("Company A status report") which is below the shared mailbox (Inquiry@company.com).
2. Search for unread emails + a subject phrase: "Company A status report"
3. Take emails that match the criteria, find the last email then check if an attachment exists.
4. If attachments exist then download the file.

The code has previously worked, but now I get an error at this line:

```
Set olFolder = oOlns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox) '// Inbox
```

The error is:

> "assignment to constant not permitted"

Library references
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
'~~> Path for the attachment
Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\Projects\Attachments"

Sub DownloadAttachmentFirstUnreadEmail()
    Dim oOlInbFiltered As Variant
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlItmF As Object, oOlAtch As Object
    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = AttachmentPath & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & " - "
    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Company A status report") 'If outlook only contain the following:
    'Looks in Inbox
    '-Personal Inbox
        '-Company A status report

    Dim olShareName As Object
    'https://superuser.com/questions/1035062/how-to-run-a-macro-on-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-2013
    Set olShareName = oOlns.CreateRecipient("Inquiry@company.com") '// Owner's email address
    Set olFolder = oOlns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox) '// Inbox
    Set oOlInb = olFolder.Folders("Company A status report")
    'Looks in Shared Inbox
    '-Personal Inbox
    '-Inquiry Inbox (Shared)
        '-Company A status report

    '~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails
    If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464271/find-an-email-starting-with-specific-subject-using-vba
    '~~> Filter all unread mails with the subject: Company A status report
    Dim Findvariable As String
    Findvariable = "Company A status report"
    Dim filterStr As String
    filterStr = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like '%" & Findvariable & "%'"
    Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict(filterStr)
    Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    'Set oOlInbFiltered = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True AND [Subject] = 'Company A status report'") - works

    'Test how many mails that are found and populated in the variable: oOlInbFiltered
    MsgBox ("Hello Test")
    Dim testp As Object
    For Each testp In oOlInbFiltered
        Debug.Print testp.Subject
    Next testp

    'Sort all the mails by ReceivedTime so the loop will start with the latest mail
    oOlInbFiltered.Sort "ReceivedTime", True 'True for Ascending. Take the last mail to the oldest. We only want the last and therefore exit the loop after we find it.
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInbFiltered
    'Debug.Print oOlItm
    '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
        If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                Debug.Print oOlAtch
                '~~> Download the attachment
                oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.FileName
                'Mark the found mail as read
                oOlItm.UnRead = False
                DoEvents
                oOlItm.Save
                Exit For
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "The Email doesn't have an attachment"
        End If
        Exit For

    Next oOlItm

    'Open the downloaded file
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = NewFileName & oOlAtch.FileName
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    'Set DataPage = wb1.Sheets("DATA")

 End Sub
```

Comment: Missing declaration of`olFolder`indicates missing`Option Explicit` (even your code includes it). Remove the outlook reference as your code looks late-bound to outlook. Maybe that causes the error as you define`olFolderInbox` as constant, what is an outlook enum (not accessible if late-bound).

Comment: This code looks familiar ;) What happens if you type these 2 lines `olShareName.Resolve` and  `If Not olShareName.Resolved Then Msgbox "Unable To resolve"` before  `Set olFolder = oOlns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)`

Comment: Yes, it's orignally yours with some minor modification. Thanks it works really good and helps me alot!! Unfortunately your suggestion still get me the same error at the same line.

Comment: The solution was to dim the object that cause the error. So I added: `Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder` before the error line `Set olFolder ...`

Comment: Why early-binding(`Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder`) , when all is prepared for late-binding(`Dim olFolder As Object`) (compatible to different outlook versions, if early-boun, only same or newer versions supported)

Comment: Thank you @ComputerVersteher. Didn't thought about that. `Dim olFolder As Object` is a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but can't comment yet.

Error might be caused by:

```
Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
```

If you change it to normal `olFolderInbox = 6` it might fix your issue.

I've got similar vba, that opens inbox and then check's e-mail details and iterate through them.

On mine I've set different `Dim's`

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Dim olSharedName As Outlook.Recipient
```

Where

```
Set Ns = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olSharedName = Ns.CreateRecipient("e'mail@domain.com") 
Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olSharedName, olFolderInbox)
```

My references are:

[image: References]

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thank you, it actually helped me alot. I tried to change my setup to no success. However you pointed me in the right direction as you have Dim your `Folder` and I haven't. So it solved my isssue. Thanks!! (Always Dim your variables..., I should know ;) )

Comment: @Wizhi Always use`Option Explicit`(and not only show in question;))!

Comment: I always use `Option Explicit` as it cause less headache... However this was strange case since it worked good before I went away. 2 weeks later when I came back the macro didn't work and I got this error message...