# How do I change the below code to make the condition: Subject contains the word True instead of the subject equals true

Tags: vba

How do I change the below code to make the condition: Subject contains the word True instead of the subject equals true.

```
 For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = True")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work if Subject contains True or RE: True or FW: True

```
 For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'True'")
```

If Subject contains additional text including True:

```
filterStr = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%True%'"
For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict(filterStr)
```

For more details please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464271/find-an-email-with-subject-starting-with-specific-text)