# Find emails by subject with not exact match

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to get all the emails from Outlook mailbox which contain part of the string in the subject.

I'm using `Items.Restrict` method to get the array of messages filtered by the certain parameter. In Python it would be like this:

`messages = Folder.Items.Restrict('[Subject] = "Some Subject is here"')`

In VBA it returns only the emails with exact match to "Some Subject is here". I need emails which contain "Some Subject" in the subject, but if I do it like this:

`messages = Folder.Items.Restrict('[Subject] = "Some Subject"')`

It returns nothing. Is there any other operator for this? Like this for example (not working):

```
messages = Folder.Items.Restrict('[Subject] like "*Some Subject is here*"')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464271/find-an-email-with-subject-starting-with-specific-text

Comment: If Python is a requirement, where does VBA fall into the picture? Take a look at the pyOutlook module: https://pyoutlook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Otherwise, could you just use the Exchange snap-in with PowerShell, or use the MS Graph API with PS?